Unresolved reference: ActivityMainBinding
I want to program an Android app in Android Studio with Kotlin, but I can't get any further because I have an error. I'm programming a tutorial and according to this tutorial I have to use ActivityMainBinding, but I can't import it or use it without importing it. What can i do?
I've tried it, to import it, I have also tried, to write something in the build.gradle file, but it won't work

try invalidating caches

Provide more information with the code you're using.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

If you created the binding in your XML file and you can't use it, try Clean Project, then Rebuild Project (from the Build dropdown menu on top of Android Studio).

check official documentation about it
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

It would be nice to add a few words about the part of the document, you are referring to.
